# Magento 2: Product price is not showing on front end

Tags: magento2

I'm new to Magento and am using Magento 2.2.6. I have uploaded product in back end but product price is not showing on front end. Kindly help me on this.

Comment: Have you set the product price?

Comment: Yes but even though its not reflecting on front end.

Comment: Do the full reindexing once and then cache:clean and then check.

Comment: please run this both commands: php bin/magento indexer:reindex and php bin/magento cache:clean and then check

Comment: Welcome. can you advise if you are using the default magento 2 themes or a custom theme?

Comment: Done with full reindexing and cache clear but same issue.

Comment: Using custom theme.

Comment: share a screenshot if possible

Comment: screenshot here- https://prnt.sc/owhuga & https://prnt.sc/owhx1z

Comment: simply run the re indexing of price index

Comment: Done with it but still facing the same issue. Is there any other way to resolve the issue.

Comment: Then it could be the problem with price block . Can you check your layout xml file for the product details page in your theme's folder. file name catalog_product_view.xml Please post your catalog_product_view.xml here